# Error during deployment ws module Apache CXF

Tags: java, apache, web-services, maven

I wrote a webservice, which is trying to implement but I error associated with the library Apache CXF.

[image]

my web pom like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>SieciowyWS</artifactId>
        <groupId>SieciowyWS</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>WebService</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <version.org.jboss.as.plugins.maven.plugin>7.3.Final</version.org.jboss.as.plugins.maven.plugin>
        <version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0>3.0.0.Final</version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0>

        <version.compiler.plugin>3.6.0</version.compiler.plugin>

        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>

        <cxf.version>2.2.9</cxf.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ws.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossws-cxf-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBOSS</id>
            <name>JBoss Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>JBOSS</id>
            <name>JBoss Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.jboss.as.plugins.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/api.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.ws.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxws-tools-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.GA</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>My execution</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsconsume</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/gen-src</sourceDirectory>
                            <wsdls>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/api.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdls>
                            <targetPackage>com.rogal.sieciowyandroid</targetPackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

I tried to also add jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

but error not disappeared.

Do I need to add some additional libraries?

I will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that your cxf lib is already provided by JBoss and you add another version in your war.

Have you tried to set the scope of the dependency in provided scope like that ?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ws.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossws-cxf-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

It seems surprising that you need to add the cxf-client jar for JBoss. I think that JBoss should have the cxf library required in its lib folder.
Besides the name of the jbossws-cxf-client jar contains the "client" word. So, I imagine that this jar is not for the server side but when you want to call a Webservice as a client.

Answer (score 0):

I added this scope.
I think the problem cxf is solved, yet throws another exception
[image]

Comment: You should not add a new answer but edit the original question or open a new question. Besides, to answer to you, we need more information that for the original question. And try to copy paste the log in the question rather than posting image.